# Using @import from clang?

Tags: ios, clang

I'd like to write some code with Sublime and clang from the Terminal.  How can I use the new module (@import) syntax with clang?  I tried adding the **-fmodules** flag but it didn't work.  With modules enabled can I also omit **-framework Foundation** flag?

```
   clang -fmodules -framework Foundation test.mm; ./a.out
```

Little test file:

```
#import <stdio.h>
// #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import Foundation;

/*

clang -fmodules -framework Foundation test.mm; ./a.out 

*/
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    NSString *hello = @"Hello";
    printf("%s\n", "hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What version of clang and OS X are you using? The frameworks have to be modularized (i.e., they have to include a module.map) which has been done in OS X 10.9 but not earlier versions. And you I believe you should be able to omit the `-framework` flag.

Comment: Mavericks... Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.75) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)

Comment: I don't understand why this is a question. Try it and see for yourself. If it links properly then obviously you can omit the explicit linking step. You could also check out Xcode's statements for building with modules and auto linking if you think there may be a new component to the command.

Comment: It's a question because I tried it and it didn't work.  It doesn't recognize the @import.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your input file is Objective-C++ (from the .mm extension) but modules aren't yet ready for C++. There's a seperate flag, -fcxx-modules, but even if you use that you're likely to get failures. To use modules you'll have to stick with C and Objective-C for now.

This should work fine for C and Objective-C with the clang from Xcode 5 and on OS X 10.9.

```
@import Foundation;

int main() {
  NSString *hello = @"Hello";
  NSLog(@"%@", hello);
}

⑆ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix

⑆ clang -fmodules main.m && ./a.out
2013-11-20 08:51:37.638 a.out[51425:507] Hello
```

Comment: Nice catch!  I was originally doing some C++ and just reused my standard filename.  I also had an older version of the compiler *.75, which didn't work.  I upgraded IB in the App Store and got *.79 and it works now.  Thanks.