# How to enable -fcxx-modules flag in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

According to discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083224/using-import-from-clang), I used .mm in my Xcode project and I need to enable `-fcxx-modules flag`.

I have Xcode8.3 and how to enable `-fcxx-modules flag`.

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of possibles methods:

1. In the `Target->Build Phases -> Compile Sources` add
   `-fcxx-modules` to the Compiler Flags column of the source files where modules are used
2. If it is always required, consider adding it to the `Target->BuildSettings->Other C++ Flags`

Comment: If your `ExCode` does not show `Other C++ Flags` option (like mine), simply manually add `OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS` setting with `$(OTHER_CFLAGS)` and `-fcxx-modules` as values (by clicking your target, then "`Editor > Add Build Setting > Add User-Defined Build Setting`" menu)